# ffmpeg: is it possible to remove part of mp3 without encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I found that I can [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390731/how-to-crop-a-mp3-from-x-to-xn-using-ffmpeg) the file or [trim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182602/trim-audio-file-using-start-and-stop-times) it, but instead I need to remove a few minutes of trash from my mp3, is it possible with ffmpeg, without reencoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the concat demuxer

Create a text file

```
file in.mp3 
inpoint 0
outpoint 2:34
file in.mp3 
inpoint 4:04
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp3
```

The segment between the `outpoint` for the first entry and `inpoint` of the second entry will be removed.